# Deleted posts can still be edited

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Deleted posts are accessible via the edit URLs, if you know the ID

e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89775/dummy-post-to-reference-in-bug-report

is available under https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/89775/edit

I spotted this with a post of mine that had been downvoted enough to earn 'peer pressure' on deletion; the original post is gone from my activity, but still accessible via edit... no idea if it works for other users posts.

Comment: To clarify, 'other users' means across ids!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Must just be your own.

Comment: this is status-bydesign imho

Comment: Ah, 'quirk' rather than bug then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bug. Users asked to be able to delete their posts, edit them while deleted, and then undelete them.

Comment: I was able to edit his deleted post even though I'm not able to see it elsewhere. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Tim, simply because you have edit privilege, imho.

Comment: @YOU even as a low rep user I can see the post this way in the edit window. Note I can't actually edit it just give edit suggestions.

Comment: @Wes, you still can suggest edits to deleted posts.