# Can I undo the deletion on questions that I deleted myself?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

Is it possible to undo the deletion of my own questions that I have deleted myself? If yes, then how can I do that?

I'm asking this because I read that users with 10k reputation can see the deleted posts, so they are still there in the database. If I delete any my question accidentally, then how can I get it back?

Comment: Just curious, why did you use `[discussion]`, `[feature-request]`, `[support]` _and_ `[bug]`? You only need one of those four. This happens every once in a while and I'm wondering how we can reduce its likelihood of occurring. Was the description on the Ask Question page confusing?

Comment: NO its not duplicate of that just check the mean of this I'm not asking for the cause I'm asking how to get back the question deleted by your own self.

Comment: closing as duplicate works a little differently on Meta SO. Here, duplicates are for any question that covers a topic that an existing FAQ also covers. I updated the FAQ to include your question and an answer, so it is now a duplicate by the Meta definition.

Answer (score 4):

There is not an easy way for you to do this, [something I have complained about before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave). If you flag one of your other posts, select "Other" and explain what you want, a moderator should be able to undelete it for you.

Comment: What about the post which didn't get answer and deleted by myself not flagged?

Comment: @avirk Just pick any of your posts and flag it, so that a moderator will see it. Tell the moderator that you just deleted a question and you would like it undeleted, and they will be able to see the question and do that for you.

Comment: Then its mean I have bad luck because I deleted them without flag.

Comment: @avirk It doesn't matter how you deleted the old post, just flag any post you have made.

Comment: You can undelete your own questions without flagging... As long as they aren't locked.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm unable to see my own deleted questions, [as we discussed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave). Hence I needed to flag when I wanted a mod to undelete one.

Comment: How can I see them to undelete them.