# Deleted posts are visible through several AJAX endpoints

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, deleted-posts

The question [How can you tell if a person is a programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895296/how-can-you-tell-if-a-person-is-a-programmer) was deleted a long time ago. However:

- anyone can see the question at [`/posts/895296/ajax-load`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/895296/ajax-load).
- anyone can see the comments at [`/posts/895296/comments`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/895296/comments).
- anyone who [can see vote counts](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) can see them at [`/posts/895296/vote-counts`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/895296/vote-counts).
- anyone can see their own votes on the post or answers at [`/posts/895296/votes`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/895296/votes).

*Related:*

- [How is the editing of deleted posts supposed to behave?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave)
- [Editing pages allow mismatched post ID and revision GUID, enabling a very minor privileges bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112708/editing-pages-allow-mismatched-post-id-and-revision-guid-enabling-a-very-minor)

Comment: The first link doesn't work for unregistered users. Doesn't work for me, either. (404 in both cases)

Comment: The links work for me too, even if I am not a 10k user on SO, nor am I an unregistered user.

Comment: @lunboks: Oops. I thought I tested both of them while logged-out. Clairfying.

Comment: @lunboks It is strange; I get a `{"up":"270","down":"-17"}` as output for the first link.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Well, you do have more than 1k reputation. Might be it enforces *that*, but doesn't check for deleted posts.

Comment: I'm not sure how much we care here...it introduces a fair amount of code duplication and complexity due to the owner and mods being able to see this content and keeping it in sync with question/show and its specific needs, etc.  Given you can see this in the data dump *anyway*, it's not really doing any harm...

Comment: Adding `/ajax-load`, from the review page, with which any user can see the see the post body, votes, tags, closers, etc..

Comment: Related: http://stackapps.com/questions/2505/stack-exchange-deleted-question-viewer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of the above routes except `/posts/12345/votes` (which *would* be much more expensive and complex) will check for permission to see the deleted content after the next build.