# Editing pages allow mismatched post ID and revision GUID, enabling a very minor privileges bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, revisions-list, deleted-posts

`8355b709-6161-47d0-bc11-cadba8dd11c1` is the GUID of a revision of the deleted-but-unlocked post [As a programmer, what are some telltale signs that you're about to get fired or laid off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443638/as-a-programmer-what-are-some-telltale-signs-that-youre-about-to-get-fired-or).

The editing URL for the post, working from the current revision, is

> [`/posts/`**`443638`**`/edit/8355b709-6161-47d0-bc11-cadba8dd11c1`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/443638/edit/8355b709-6161-47d0-bc11-cadba8dd11c1)

This page correctly fails to load for unregistered users. However, if I replace the post ID in the URL with one from a regular post that anyone can edit, the editor will load the content of the deleted post for anyone:

> [`/posts/`**`10668`**`/edit/8355b709-6161-47d0-bc11-cadba8dd11c1`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10668/edit/8355b709-6161-47d0-bc11-cadba8dd11c1)

I realize that this might be the least significant bug I've reported, as it requires a GUID that you probably can't even get without being able to see the post in the first place. Still, for thoroughness, here it is.

**edit:** Relatedly, `/revisions/ID/GUID/diff` endpoint doesn't seem to have any privileges enforced.

> [`/revisions/443638/8355b709-6161-47d0-bc11-cadba8dd11c1/diff`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/443638/8355b709-6161-47d0-bc11-cadba8dd11c1/diff)

Comment: I wouldn't call this particularly urgent (it doesn't let you do more than suggest an edit unless you can already edit on the site), but nice to know. FWIW, you can also view comments on deleted posts if you have the URL.

Comment: related: @Shog9 Re: comments: I previously [reported that as a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111858/privileges-arent-properly-enforced-by-the-ajax-endpoints-for-comments-or-vote-c) and have recently been (ab)using it in [my deleted question viewing user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2505/stack-exchange-deleted-question-viewer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access control of `/posts/:id/edit/:guid` was already fixed at some point.

I have fixed the other access control bug and related ones affecting `/revisions` routes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm declining this as it has been open for two years now.

If this becomes particularly worrying we'll plug it, but at the moment forcing users to guess the GUID seems to be the by-design choice in many parts of the code.

Comment: tries 000...0001 (nope), 000...0002 (nope), 000...0003 (nope) - I'll get one eventually! just you wait and see!

Comment: you forgot `000...0000`, which actually has some more chances to work :-D

Comment: @Skilvvz I get your joking, but pretty sure {000...000} ([`Guid.Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.empty(v=vs.110).aspx)) isn't a valid GUID. And by (in)valid, I mean one that you shouldn't use in practice. If your system generates a {000...000} GUID, your PRNG may be broken.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, it's the default value of System.Guid in .net, that's why it has a bigger chance to work than any other unspecified value (think: bug writing unitialized value to db)

Comment: Fair enough. Do you use use Version 4 (random) UUIDs? In that case, 122 bits of security definitely ought to be enough for anybody. :P

Comment: @Sklivvz ahhh.... Oh