# Why can't I see comments on a deleted answer?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, comments, deleted-answers

Ok so I have a [deleted answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116647/155556)

I see that it says:

> show **6** more comments
>   [image: 6 more]

So I click on it and it has an error:
[image: error...]

Why is it doing that?
Why can't I see the comments that might have led to my answer's deletion?

Answer (score 8):

In the code changes implemented to fix [deleted content inadvertently visible via AJAX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111858/deleted-posts-are-visible-through-several-ajax-endpoints), I didn't consider this case...it will be corrected in the next build.