# Viewing deleted questions edit hack

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

On a comment of a post I read recently, I found out that you can go to any deleted post, and if you really want to see the post, you can force it into edit mode. If you turn the `question` part of the url into `posts`, and substitute the question title for `/edit` onto the back end of the link, you have got yourself viewing a deleted question. For example, turn this link

> https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/love-problem-solution-baba-ji-91-815934087

giving this result

[image: 404 page]

into this link

> https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/10563/edit

giving this result

[image: Not 404 page]

You can view the question in a less efficient way. You can't see the poster or the answers or any of that other fun stuff, but I am still pretty sure this shouldn't happen. As animuson suggested in the comments, it might only occur for registered users, but it works on other sites as well

#### Note

<strike>This does not work on MSO</strike>

As noted by Seth in the comments, you have to have the [Retag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions) privilege in order to use this bug.

---

<sub>I am pretty sure this has been posted on meta before, but I can't find it, so mark it as a duplicate so that I have something to reference</sub>

Comment: Hrm. I get "This post is deleted and cannot be edited."

Comment: Yep. Although it's a single line of plain text, not a full page or anything... Maybe the hack only works for registered users?

Comment: @animuson I can see the whole question. It looks just like the normal edit screen

Comment: You have an account there. I don't.

Comment: I have confirmed this on StackOverflow. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201127/can-someone-find-me-example-of-sprite-sheet-animation-java-code) points to a deleted question, but [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10201127/edit) leads to the edit page. Curiously, the edit link suggests that my edits need to be peer reviewed.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate.

Comment: @Daedalus that would be why I said it was a duplicate. Stack Exchange doesn't have the best search feature

Comment: @CodyGuldner Either way, here's the original question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave

Comment: @Daedalus This is regarding the legitimate editing of posts that are being viewed by 10K users, not the illegitimate viewing of deleted posts

Comment: @animuson This only works if you have the retag privilege or higher on the specific site.

Comment: @animuson Hmm... I get the "deleted, can't be edited" message on [gamedev.se], where I have ~250 rep... Interesting

Comment: @Doorknob You actually have 249 rep. And to my knowledge, the retag priviledge is awarded at 500 rep

Comment: @Cody Ah, close enough, I was too lazy to check. :P So you have to have 500+ rep to use the hack? EDIT: oh okay, I just read all the comments.

Comment: @CodyGuldner I don't see how I could have seen that; your question above describes the same thing in the linked post; it makes no mention of 10k users, or the legitimacy of the action.

Comment: @Doorknob That is what seth said. And it makes sense, because I can't use it on MSO

Comment: I can do it on MSO, so it certainly works here too. I get a 404 on the music link to though (I don't have an account there, much less 500 rep).

Comment: @Daedalus That user has over 10,000 rep on stack overflow, and he is saying that he gets an error when he trys to edit deleted posts. Which is a legitimate action for a 10K user

Comment: Speaking of that.. You are getting hit with the spam too huh?

Comment: @CodyGuldner The comments say that, yes, my point though, is that your question does not c.c

Comment: @Seth What do you mean?

Comment: @Daedalus These are 2 different questions

Comment: "love problem solution baby ji" is one of the spam questions that have been popping up all over the network.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate... just not of the question that it was closed as duplicate of. Reopening.

Comment: @random That is an odd closure as well, but I'll hold off on reopening that until I can re-read it in the morning with my good friend caffeine by my side.

Comment: One day we'll find that master question

Comment: I think it got deleted actually.. (cc @random) Though I suppose you mods can search deleted questions.

Comment: I think the currently-linked duplicate does an acceptable job of addressing the situation now. There are other duplicates (some of which could use some cleanup), but this one at least stands a reasonable chance of having a useful answer.

Comment: @Shog9 Then why did Anna reopen it when it was already closed as a duplicate for this question? All you did was post an answer on that question instead of this one

Comment: @CodyGuldner: The duplicate here makes sense. Shog's answer on the duplicate explains perfectly well that this behavior is by-design (users with full edit privileges *can* submit edits on delete posts), and that this isn't a "hack" but a feature (it may not make much sense, but it's a feature nonetheless).