# Edit suggestion submitted on deleted answer

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, deleted-answers

Minor bug, but apparently a user was able to submit an edit suggestion on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17054171/825789) after I deleted it. I tried to handle it from the answer's *edit* link, and the system didn't let me – I got a popover error message saying that edit suggestions on deleted posts could not be reviewed. However, I was able to review it by following the [review link on the notification](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2296682) I got for that edit. Also, another user had already reviewed it before me.

I'm not sure what's wrong here, but I believe the system should not have allowed the edit suggestion to be submitted in the first place. And, after it was, it should have prevented me and others from reviewing it.

As I said, it looks like a minor bug, as it's about a deleted answer. I'm just posting this for the record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue appears to be fixed (at least partially).

At one point in the past, you could hack the edit link and be able to edit deleted posts. The way to edit your answer would have been: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17054171/edit.

However, this link (for me, under 10k rep) shows:

> This post is deleted and cannot be edited.

It is still possible to have suggested edits in the queue on posts that have been deleted, but I suspect that the edit happened before the deletion. It doesn't seem possible to improve the edit:

> [image: It can't be improved]

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me today on this post : https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/869852 .

I wasn't able to summit a 5th suggestion because of this [pseudo-edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Mb0.png) of an answer which was removed later, moderator was still able to accept / reject this edit even if of this state, but with my reputation which wasn't as high as necessary to read it (10k), I didn't see it in my susggestion page.

Pseudo-edit that block my 5th edit suggestion:

[image: Pseudo-edit that block my 5th edit suggestion]