# Suggested edit on deleted answer still reviewable

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a deleted question (or answer) with a suggested edit.  I used [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40512303/2415822) (10k only) on Stack Overflow.
2. Click the edit button, observe the "This post has been deleted; no edit suggestions are available" message.
3. Open the edit in the Suggested Edits review window (right click on the edit button -> open in new tab/window or copy link).  [Link for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14239953).
4. Observe that the suggested edit can be reviewed though the answer has been deleted.

Comment: Well, since deleted posts [can be edited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132212/152859) (naturally by those who see them, i.e. users with 10k rep) the bug in my opinion is not that the edit can be reviewed, but that the edit link does not allow you to reach the review.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123660/suggested-edits-to-posts-which-no-longer-exist-should-be-automatically-removed

Comment: @ShadowWizard ah I see.  So I would like clarity on two things: 1. should this suggested edit (on a deleted answer) be reviewable?  2. Should the review be reachable one way but not the other?

Comment: 1. IMO, yes. 2. No, it should be consistent.

Comment: These normally get invalidated within 15 minutes of deletion - at least they used to be. I'm not sure why this didn't happen here, considering the First Post review *did* get invalidated correctly.

Comment: Related: [Edit suggestion submitted on deleted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184029/edit-suggestion-submitted-on-deleted-answer?rq=1)

Comment: @animuson So did something go wrong with the invalidation on this particular post?  Maybe because the answer was deleted with the question?

Comment: It's not a dupe because ***that's***: "When the post that a suggested edit belongs too gets deleted(by the author), so should the suggested edit.", and ***this is***: someone (presumably not the Moderator or the OP) deleted the post and it's been edited; and the editor's edits are reviewable. So the edit ought to be reviewed before becoming visible, and possibly making the deleted post eligible for reopening. --- So not a dupe.