# Cannot edit self-deleted answers if there was a pending suggested edit at the time of deletion

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, deleted-answers

After I wrote a [not-so-good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304713/158100), I decided to delete it. At the time of deletion, there was a pending suggested edit which I didn't bother to check.

Assuming I want to salvage my answer before I undelete it, I desperately want to edit it to counter the unwarranted and anonymous down votes.

Clicking the edit link doesn't work though. I'm greeted with an error:

> [This post has been deleted, no edit suggestions are available.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgBv8.png)

I'm not interested in [suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/55458) from some anonymous editor; I want to salvage my post.

This is related to [Suggested edit on deleted answer still reviewable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286772/suggested-edit-on-deleted-answer-still-reviewable), but that is from a reviewer point of view, which I'm really not interested in, nor care about.

Is my only option to undelete the answer, get a few more down votes, reject the edit and delete again? Or am I at the mercy of reviewers to review that edit I'm not going to use anyway. There must be a better way, if only for OP's.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Once https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286772/suggested-edit-on-deleted-answer-still-reviewable gets fixed, this will no longer be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

For me the best option is to simply allow to review that edit. Once you are done with that, you can go ahead and edit yourself, since your review is always binding. It seems there is need for much development time to change that.

We don't have to care about reputation that is lost on the suggested edit: once undeleted, the approved edit will count again, and if it is never undeleted, there is nothing really lost.

Another option is to simply invalidate the suggested edit, but then something great might get lost in the process.

Comment: I can live with the first option, thanks.

Comment: The second option is not that good, but might solve some issues from the first one, if any.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you delete the answer, the edit suggestion will still be visible in your inbox:

[image]

If you click on that inbox item, you can still review the suggested edit.

Since you're the owner of the post, the Improve and Reject and Edit buttons will still be available (they're not available to other reviewers), so you can edit from there. If you think the suggested edit is useful, you can improve it, otherwise you can reject and edit it.

This works, I tested it by posting an answer in the [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/349538), suggesting an edit to it with my sock puppet, deleting my post and then reviewing the edit as Reject and Edit. If you have more than 10k reputation you can see the timeline of that answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/304806/timeline), otherwise, [here is the edit my sock puppet suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/55496).