# Someone deleted my question, how can I undelete it?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, questions

Is it ok to undelete my post after a moderator deleted it? Do I need a certain amount of reputation for that? Someone who has 10K rep, can undelete others posts, is it the same for your own? Does it depend who deleted it?

There is a question which has been deleted by a moderator called goldPseudo, and I told him that I got a new plan to improve it, but he did not not take into account what I said. I was about to improve it but he deleted.

Comment: for those curious about the site, goldPseudo is a moderator on Islam

Comment: I do wonder whether *who* the mod was is important here.

Comment: I considered removing the second paragraph while I edited, but many users say "moderator" inaccurately, and in this case it's accurate, so I left the background.

Comment: @KateGregory You could suppose to put “I said” instead of “Said I”, because it doesn’t sound well in grammatical point.

Comment: You can edit your own question as much as you like @dreadbolt

Comment: @KateGregory Ok. I just shared an advice to you for next time.

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: You can't undelete your own post if a moderator deleted it. The best way to deal with this is to (significantly) improve the post and flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can edit your post while it's still in a deleted state. Once you've addressed all the faults with it that caused it to be deleted you can raise a custom moderator flag to get it undeleted.

If for some reason you can't edit your deleted post you could do one of the following...

- Raise an issue on your site's meta with a link to the post and the new text, moderators monitor the site meta so they can replace the text and undelete the post
- Create a custom moderator message with the new text in it. This is probably only useful if the post is really simple
- Abandon the deleted post and create a new post with the new information in it.

Non-moderators no matter what their rep cannot undelete posts that moderators have deleted. 10K users can undelete posts that original posters, other 10K users, or Roomba has deleted.

Comment: Also, its worth ensuring the edits are *substantial*, dosen't change the core of the question, and are, well, worth undeleting.

Comment: Well, the problem was that, when I entered in laptop. And I try to edit my post but later, it shows me this: “you are not allowed to edit it any longer because your post is deleted”.

Comment: So, in that case what should I do to edit it while it is deleted by a moderator?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah, I know

Comment: @JourneymanGeek But now? Is there any solution for it?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Unless it's locked, I'm pretty sure the only reason you couldn't edit your own deleted post is if it's a self-deleted question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179769/132874

Comment: @goldPseudo Oops, I meant on locked not deleted

Comment: @JourneymanGeek What should I do in order to unlock it? “Because”, myself I can’t and neither to ask a new question I can’t, because I got a ban message. So, in that case what should I do?

Comment: @Dreadbot Ask on the site's meta.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you please join to my [chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1259/alpha-bayron)? Because, I need to discuss something with you, if you don’t mind.